# how to Change duplicated rows with blank, keep first in range of columns in the dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to change value of duplicated rows to blank in range of columns ?  I have 20 const columns and then number and names of columns are dynamically changed. For specific columns i used code below:

```
    remove2 = lambda x: df[x].duplicated(keep='first')  

    df.loc[remove2('PKW'), 'PKW'] = ""
```

I mean instead of  'PKW' we blank in  range of 20 to the last column of dataframe including last one of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.update(df.iloc[:, -20:].mask(df.iloc[:, -20:]
            .apply(lambda x: x.duplicated())).fillna(''))
```